# How to maintain many Azure resources and deployments in one git repo?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment, azure-webapps

I have a project that consists of an Azure webapp, a PostgreSQL on Azure, and multiple Azure functions for background ETL workflows. I also have a local Python package that I need to access from both the webapp and the Azure functions.

How can I structure configuration and script deployment for those resources from a single git repo?

Any suggestions or pointers to good examples or tutorials would be very appreciated.
All the Azure tutorials that I've seen are only for small and simple projects.

For now, I've hand-written an admin.py script that does e.g. the webapp and function deployments by creating a Python package, creating ZIP files for each resource and doing ZIP deployments. This is getting messy, and now I want to have QA and PROD versions, and I need to pass secrets so that the DB is reachable, and it's getting more complex. Is there either a nice way to structure this packaging / deployment, or a tool to help with it? For me, putting everything in Kubernetes is not the solution, at least the DB already exists. Also, Azure DevOps is not an option, we are using Gitlab CI, so eventually I want to have a solution that can run on CI/CD there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will help complete but here we go.

Instead of using a hand-written `admin.py` script, try using a yaml pipeline flow. For Gitlab, they have https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/ that you can use to get started. From what you've indicated, I would recommend having several [job steps](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#introduction) in your yaml pipeline that will build and package your web and function apps. For deployment, you can make use of [environments](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/).  Have a look at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html as well which illustrates how you can create downstream pipelines.

From a deployment standpoint, the current integration I've found between Azure and GitLab leaves me with two recommendations:

1. Leverage the `script` command of yaml to continue zipping your artifacts use Azure CLI (I would assume you can install the tools during the pipeline) to zip deploy.
2. Keep your code inside the GitLab repo and utilize Azure Pipelines to handle the CI/CD for you.

I hope you find this helpful.